# if bitcoin miner(s) changed the UTXO set would the bitcoin nodes reject the blocks?

Tags: bitcoin-core, utxo

if so, would this cause a Fork? or what would happen?

Comment: Every node has their own UTXO set. Nobody knows or cares about what miners do in theirs. If they produce an invalid block however (for example because it spends a UTXO that doesn't exist), that block will be rejected.

Comment: wow if this is the real Pieter Wuille - i am honored to haveu answer this noobie question - thank you !  i asked this question because of what Faketoshi said: 'If a court orders mining pools to seize funds, they will modify their software to do it, or be shut down'    - i thought this couldnt happen because nodes would reject - but can you explain what would really happen? thanks in advance - i am learning - long way to go

Comment: @user100601: Hey, welcome. Could you please edit your question to put the clarifying information there instead of the comments? Thanks!